# Removing R flag from rewrite rule stops it from working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a fairly simple htaccess rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([^/]+)/?$ /portfolio-categories/$1/ [R,L]
```

This works fine. However, if I remove the R I get a 404. Presumably it's redirecting to different URL, but with the R I can't see where.

I had thought that the effect should be the same (at least in terms of the page that is returned, obviously the R flag adds an extra HTTP request).

How can I fix this? How can I debug this?

Edit: here are the rest of my rules. I don't think they should affect this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([^/]+)/?$ /portfolio-categories/$1/ [L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: do you have any other rules? specifically ones that will affect `/portfolio-categories/`?

Comment: None that I think should affect this. See my edit.

Comment: If you're using some kind of framework, you'll need to go through the framework to do this. If you internally rewrite, then the framework still sees "portfolio" so it doesn't know what to do with that.

Comment: How come? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of mod_rewrite?